# escape ("<") special chracters in c#

Tags: c#, html

I have a problem with results are empty because of special characters like `<` are not searching in my query results so what I have done is this code (I have already tested this with `Regex` and `WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt;")` it always returns an empty result.)

```
private IEnumerable < string > GetRowValues(DataRow dr) {
  foreach(DataColumn col in DataResult.Columns)
    yield return replaceSpecialChar(dr[col].ToString());
}

private string replaceSpecialChar(string text) {

  if (text.Contains("<")) {

    text = text.Replace("<", "&lt");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);
  }

  return text;
}
```

Comment: You're replacing "<" as "&lt" not "&lt;" as it should be. By replacing "<" with "&lt;" you are _encoding_ the text, not decoding it (I'm not sure if this is intentional). Plain form -> non-plain form = encoding. Non-plain form -> plain form = decoding.

Comment: yes i have tested with "&lt;" it's the same it's empty result

Comment: I'm not sure how you get a "result". Your goals and your code aren't especially clear. I don't see any evidence of "searching" some query results.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up encode and decode

```
string result = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("<"); //&lt;
```